# A div css transition only goes one way and then forgets about it

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So i have this div and I want to smoothly scale it on hover. Everything goes well and it gets bigger smoothly. After I move my mouse away, however, it just instantly returns to it's normal state without a smooth transition.

```
.dashboardInfoBox {
    width: 190px;
    display: flex;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 4px 6px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    padding: 11px 17px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.dashboardInfoBox:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}
```

```
<div class="dashboardInfoBox">
    test text
</div>
```

I have no idea how to force the transition to go both ways... Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: move `transition: 0.2s linear`-rule to `.dashboardInfoBox`-selector's body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the parent element `dashboardInfoBox`the transition property, that should fix the Problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `transition` in your hover state (`.dashboardInfoBox:hover`), move it into your regular class (`.dashboardInfoBox`).

What happens is that your transition works only when you're hovering over the element.

```
.dashboardInfoBox {
    width: 190px;
    display: flex;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 4px 6px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    padding: 11px 17px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.dashboardInfoBox:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: ah ok, i get it noe) thanks a lot!